# Error 404 serving media files in a Django app hosted on DigitalOcean

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

I am making a small Django app and I want to use files uploaded via Django admin panel in production
This is from my settings.py file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
MEDIA_URL = ''
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR
```

I trust admin uploaded files and want to serve them easily(without Amazon S3 and similar services), so i tried to place the uploaded files with other static files

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images')
```

After uploading an image via admin panel i run `python manage.py collectstatic` in the DigitalOcean console. Whenever i try to access the image i get Error 404, while all other static files(which are real static files, not uploaded via admin panel) load successfully

I did the same thing locally and there is no problem, everything loads as expected(`DEBUG=True` is set both locally and on DigitalOcean). Is it some security measure that doesnt let uploaded files end up in static? How can i bypass it if i trust files uploaded via admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using `manage.py runserver` to run you website

first make sure that the media is being served in your main `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
...
] + [
static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
]
```

then you can use runserver with --insecure to run your website with or without `DEBUG=True`

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80 --insecure
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cmdoption-runserver-insecure

as in the django documentation this is not the recommended way to serve your files, you should use a reverse proxy like nginx or apache

or if you really dont want to use a reverse proxy, you could give whitenoise a try
http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

Comment: I tried adding what you suggested in the main `urls.py` and deploying, but i still get 404 trying to access images. The app is ran by DigitalOcean with the `gunicorn --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm django_app.wsgi` command

Comment: if you're using gunicorn you're better off using nginx to serve all your needed files.

Comment: or you can use `manage.py runserver` with configuration in the answer